# Programmatically UIButton in ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I use following code to set a button. It works fine but when setting it in a window which is scrollable the button is still fixed on the screen and the view is scrolling behind it.
How do I make the button follow along with the scroll.
If I set a button using the IB it does follow the scroll. And that is what I want but now I wish to use the programmatically method.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Add button to UIScrollView no to self.view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `button` to `UIViewController`'s view.
Change code bellow:

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

to following:

```
[scrollView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Works fine. Solves a problem for me when I want to set pictures in the button from a plist.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `UIButton` to the scroll view instead of the view controller's view. E.g., replace:

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

with

```
[myScrollView addSubview:button];
```